# PHP How to check if text field matches var

Tags: php, validation

Well then, this is likely to be the n-th time someone is asking this, but honestly I didn't grab anything useful spending the last hour or so on Google. What I want to do is rather trivia, or so I thought. I have this working in Java Script but want to move it to PHP. In brief:

- declare a var with a static value
- add text field into which user is asked to enter value of above var
- check if field is a) empty, b) non-empty mismatch, or c) non-empty match

My (limited) PHP wisdom has lead me into believing it ought to be something like the below, but apparently it's not. I'd very much appreciate any insight, tha.

```
<?php
$coconew = "blah";

if (isset ($_POST["cocosub"])) {
    if ($_POST["cocoval"] == "") {
        echo "empty";
    } else {
        if ($_POST["cocoval"] != $coconew) {
            echo "mismatch";
        } else {
            echo "match";
        }
    }
}
?>

<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" id="cocosub" method="post">
    <div>
        <?php echo $coconew; ?>
        <input type="text" id="cocoval">
        <input type="submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_POST["cocosub"])){

    $input = trim($_POST["cocoval"]);

    if($input == ""){
        echo "empty";
    } elseif($input != $_SESSION["coconew"]){
        echo "mismatch";
    } else {
        echo "match";
    }
}

$_SESSION["coconew"] = substr(md5(uniqid()), 0, 5);

?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" id="cocosub" method="post">
<div>
    <?php echo $_SESSION["coconew"]; ?>
    <input type="text" id="cocoval" name="cocoval">
    <input type="submit" name="cocosub">
</div>
</form>
```

You needed to add name="cocosub" to the Submit button element in order for the first if(isset(...)) condition to be true. That's why the script didn't work. Also, instead of id, you need to use the name="cocoval" in the input text field as well in order for it to carry over into $_POST.

Comment: First, thanks all for the superfast response. Been thinking into the trim part before. Sadly, I must admit the value of coconew isn't just a simple text string. Just tried it and worked like a charm. However, the original code always returns mismatch rather than match as would be expeted. I'll post it here:$coconew = substr (md5 (uniqid ()), 0, 5);

Comment: ouch, 5 min timeout...First, thanks all for the superfast response. Been thinking into the trim part before. Sadly, I must admit the value of coconew isn't just a simple text string. Just tried it and worked like a charm. However, the original code always returns mismatch rather than match as would be expeted. I'll post it here: $coconew = substr (md5 (uniqid ()), 0, 5); which gives something in the form of 5g3xL or similar. I wouldn't have thought there'd be a difference, but obviously there is.

Comment: Using uniqid() would generate a random string each time the form is used. You're basically trying to compare input text with a random string that's randomized after the form has been submitted...how could there ever be a match? What end product are you trying to get here? Not a CAPTCHA is it?

Comment: Something the likes. Since I have it working in Java Script, I had thought it possible to implement in PHP. Might be less trouble to split form and script to export the var. Any clues?

Comment: In that case use a session variable. I updated my answer above. Script works now with substr(md5(uniqid(...))

Comment: Amazing how close I had been ;) That works excellent, thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change

```
<input type="text" id="cocoval">
```

to

```
<input type="text" name="cocoval">
```

There are other (and probably better) ways to do this, but you are on the right track.

Comment: The script still won't work. The if(isset($_POST["cocosub"])) condition will always be false until he either changes cocosub to cocoval or adds the name="cocosub" attribute to the submit button.

Answer (score 1):

`$_POST` only looks for the `name` attribute of form elements, so modify your form as such:

```
<?php
$coconew = "blah";

if (isset ($_POST["cocoval"])) {
    if ($_POST["cocoval"] === "") {
        echo "empty";
    } else {
        if ($_POST["cocoval"] !== $coconew) {
            echo "mismatch";
        } else {
            echo "match";
        }
    }
}
?>


<form  id="cocosub" method="post">
    <div>
        <?php echo $coconew; ?>
        <input type="text" id="cocoval" name="cocoval">
        <input type="submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

(I made a few other changes, you want to check `isset` on the element, not the form, it will POST to the same page if you don't give it an attribute [so no need to add the `echo`], and adding better type checking in your php)

Comment: One problem remaining with this is that $coconew presumably needs to be a dynamic variable, not the same for every user. The OP may already be aware of this, but for anyone unsure, the first line would probably involve $_SESSION in some way...

Answer (score 1):

in addition to the other answers already posted, you might also be interested in PHP's session support (depending on how "static" you need your static variables to be).   That's where you'd put `$cocoval` and any other variables if you need to save their values across multiple requests for the same URL by the same user.  See here for more info:

http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php and
http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php